# Is it possible to implement Windows and Database authentication in a MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a project that currently validates User/Password/Role using `RoleProvider` and a basic Template CRUD.

These credentials get validated comparing data on a SQL table that contains those values... the project was planned for about 60 managers but it worked so well that it will be implemented on a company level so it will be used for about 200+ employees so managing the users like this:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
     <authorization>
        <allowusers="DOMAIN\USER"/>
     </authorization>
<authentication>
```

On the webconfig it's not manageable... what I have on mind its allow the entire company to enter the website (prompt Windows Login) but redirect to an Error/Access Denied view, only when they don't exist in the `users` table.

My current validation looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Login(usuario u, string retornaUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var usuario = db.user.Where(x => x.username == u.username && x.pass == u.pass ).FirstOrDefault();
            var pass = db.user.Where(x => x.username != u.username || x.pass != u.pass ).FirstOrDefault();

            if (usuario != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(u.user, false);
                Session["uname"] = u.user.ToString();

                if (usuario != null)
                {
                    return Redirect("~/Home/Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    //ViewBag.Message = "NULL";

                    TempData["Message"] = "Session finished.";
                    return Redirect("~/Account/Login");
                }
            } else
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "USERNAME/PASSWORD DOESNT EXIST";
                return Redirect("~/Account/Login");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Is it possible to compare windows credentials (only username) in the database?

Comment: Why don't you use the AspNetUsersRole table and do authentication on the controllers for them? Then if they arent authenticated, return them to the `Error` screen

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, but how could I capture the login and then compare it in the database? @JamesS

Comment: The issue here is you wont have access to the Windows identity (Name) unless they login. So if they do login via Windows authentication, and they do not exist in the database, showing them an error just doesn't make sense IMO. An alternative would be if they dont exist but login via windows, add them to the db in the background.

Comment: So you would need to give each user a log in. and assign a role against each (for example, 'Manager', 'sales' etc) using the AspNetUserRoles table. At the top of the controllers have something like `[Authorize(Roles = "Sales, Editor")]` which would mean that someone without one of them roles would NOT be able to view the pages from that controller.

Comment: Can't allow everyone to get in the application, by managing I meant if a user isn't a manager anymore I need to delete it manually on the CRUD or create it if an employee gets a promotion... @mxmissile

Comment: Exactly, I already have the ´domain\username´, ´role´ for the current managers in the database, so it'll be like if the user auth is true then capture ´domain\user´ and compare it on the database, if true redirect to index, else error view. @JamesS

Comment: I am confused a little bit it looks like you have Windows Auth enabled but are forcing them to perform a sign in through a log in page?.  That seems counter Intuitive.  Is that true or am i missing something?  If you are using windows authentication what I would do is migrate your role membership to AD groups and set your role membership to AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider in your app config. This would allow your users to not have to sign in however in the back ground if you want to check role membership you just need to call User.IsInRole("AD GROUP HERE") and direct them from there.

Comment: Currently I create manually user/pass, and I need to replace it for a windows auth, BUT I only need to give access to certain users and if possible make it manageable on a CRUD, so it's kinda impossible (?) to manage it on a user level plus the user table has relevant values assigned to the username to run the program. @Bearcat9425